# Can we use compiled .jasper file in iReport API to generate reports?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Why do we use **.jrxml** file and compile it within the code evertime the report has to be generated.

Can we use already compiled **.jasper** file using **iReport API** to generate reports?

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: `Why do we use .jrxml file and compile it within the code evertime the report has to be generated.` - it is your choice, "to compile or not to complie"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the compiled .Jasper file to generate reports in iReport.
If i open a .Jasper file in iReport it automatically generate a .JRXML file for the same .Jasper file and then you can generate report.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, compiling the .jrxml file is not required if the templates are not going to be changed.

```
private String jasperFile = "/path/to/yourReport.jasper";
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFile,
                reportParametrs,
                dataSource);
```